# Regular Expression Validation PHP

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to get this to work for some time now but can't. Here is my problem:

I have the following reg. expression: `(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?`. I'm trying to validate a URL.

The problem is when I have for example:

"`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK8mJJJvaes<br />Hello`" (this is how it saves in the database using nl2br)

It validates up to this:`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK8mJJJvaes<br`. I've read that the problem might be because of the `\S*` in the reg. expression. But if I take that out it only validates `https://www.youtube.com/`.

I've also thought of adding a space before the `<br />`, but I don't know if their is a better solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated :).

Full Code:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$finalMsg = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK8mJJJvaes<br />Hello';

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $finalMsg, $url)){
       // make the urls hyper links
       $matches = array_unique($url[0]);
       foreach($matches as $match) {
              $replacement = "<a href=".$match." target='_blank'>{$match}</a>";
              $finalMsg = str_replace($match,$replacement,$finalMsg);
       }
 }
```

Comment: well `\S*` will match any number of non whitespace characters (tabs, spaces, newlines...etc). So soon at it hits a whitespace (such as the space in `<br />`) it will stop matching.

Comment: Yeah I read about that but if I take that out it only validates the domain name. And no I want everything but the `<br />` tag.

Comment: If you want to match the whitespace, you would likely use `.*` to mean any character including whitespace.

Comment: If you are matching specifically a youtube url, then you would likely want to match something like `.*?v=\w+` which would match everything up until the end of the `v` parameter.

Comment: No, not only a youtube URL that's just an example.

Comment: Well you could also change the `\S` to be a list of characters to stop at with a negated character list by preceding the list with a caret symbol like `[^<>\s]*` which would be all characters except less than, greater than or whitespace. Technically `[^\s]` is the same as `\S` you just include a few more chars.

Comment: If the text is HTML, it'd be better to use DOM and search for URL's inside each text node instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S[^<]*)?/
```

This will at least validate your given URL, and any other that ends with a tag...
Test it here: https://regex101.com/

**EDIT:** Isn't matching root paths. The solution from @Jonathan Kuhn in the comments is the best one:

```
/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/[^\s<]*)?/
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Just revisiting some old answers and I'm irritated why I commented like I did.. I don't see the problem though, your code works. :D

Although this short piece of code would do the same:

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK8mJJJvaes<br />Hello";
$regex = '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/[^\s<]*)?/';

// make the URLs hyperlinks
$url = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $url);

echo $url;
```

Comment: Because this won't find and replace the url in a string of text.

Comment: Yeah, noticed, sry. i thought you would only validate. Didn't read it all^^